# Why when I paint, and the mouse is moving in the window, the painting is not done at the same time everywhere? (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi

After asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70667296/how-to-create-a-double-buffer-for-painting-a-window-in-wm-paint-with-transparenc?noredirect=1#comment124951520_70667296), I changed my code. It works, but when WM_PAINT paints the window and the cursor is moving in it, the painting is not done at the same time everywhere. Here you have a [video](https://files.fm/f/z7tr82j73) to see it better. This is my WM_PAINT:

```
    //TV is a struct with the dimensions of the window.
    //BitmapBuffer is the bitmap containing the painting.

    static int cont;
    cont++;
    HDC HDc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    HDc = BeginPaint(identifier, &ps);

    Gdiplus::Graphics lienzo (HDc);

    AlphaBlend(HDc, 0, 0, TV.width+4, TV.height+4, buffer, 0, 0, TV.width+4, TV.height+4, CopyInfo);

    EndPaint(identifier, &ps);
```

Since the problem is when moving the mouse, maybe the WM_NCHITTEST message has something to do with it:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST: 

    POINTS point1 = MAKEPOINTS(lParam); 
    POINT point2;

    point2.x = point1.x;
    point2.y = point1.y;


    ScreenToClient(hwnd, &point2); 

    if (PtInRegion(region, point2.x, point2.y)) 
    {
        if (inWindow == false) //inWindow is true when the cursor is in the window
        {
            inWindow = true;
            TrackMouseEvent(&structure);
            Repaint(); //this function repaint the buffer and after call invalidrect
        }

        return HTCLIENT; 
    }
    else
    {
        if (inWindow == true)
        {
            inWindow = false;
            Repaint();
        }

        return HTTRANSPARENT; 
    }

    break;
```

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Comment: @YangXiaoPo - MSFT My code has about 2000 lines . I'm trying but I can't reduce it too much.

Comment: this question requires understanding another question, which is not recommended. please try to explain the video in maybe a two-frame drawing depicting not/working areas, because even the video is not clear to tell what is your expected output

Comment: as for the code, you may share reduced&functional code to a github repo or a github gist to help us to help you.

Comment: What does `Repaint()` do?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see the problem, because your code doesn't define Repaint. However, you should be using [InvalidateRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) to tell Windows which area is being updated.
THAT SAID...
Windows is hard to program for updating images with out using a double buffering technique. This is when you draw to a memory (bitmap) then bitblt the bitmap to the screen.

You find this answer useful [Reduce flicker with GDI+ and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197948/reduce-flicker-with-gdi-and-c)